# Filter an API response

Tags: filter, travel-time

I've got a response from an API that shows a particular train journey and when the train stops at different stations. I want to calculate the time that passes between it departing one station, and arriving at another, using Python.

I've tried:

```
date = '2024/01/19'
ServiceUID = "W56769"

urlrequest = requests.get(f"http://api.rtt.io/api/v1/json/service/"+ServiceUID+'/'+date))
apioutput = json.loads(r5.content)
filtered = apioutput['locations']

def find_departure(stationA):
    for a in filtered:
        if a['crs'] == stationa:   
            return a['gbttBookedDeparture']
station = "BEL"
print(find_departure(station))
```

But this just gets me the first entry to CRS in the json, rather than looking up a specific station.

This is the json response from the API:

> {'serviceUid': 'W56769', 'runDate': '2024-01-19', 'serviceType':
> 'train', 'isPassenger': True, 'trainIdentity': '2H61', 'powerType':
> 'DMU', 'trainClass': 'S', 'atocCode': 'SR', 'atocName': 'ScotRail',
> 'performanceMonitored': True, 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'locations':
> [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS', 'crs': 'INV', 'description': 'Inverness',
> 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0700', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True,
> 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '5'}, {'tiploc': 'CLHY',
> 'description': 'Clachnaharry', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': False,
> 'isPublicCall': False}, {'tiploc': 'CLUNSIB', 'description': 'Clunes
> I.B.', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS', 'description': 'Inverness',
> 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime': '0700'}], 'destination':
> [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick', 'workingTime': '113100',
> 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': False, 'isPublicCall': False},
> {'tiploc': 'BEAULY', 'crs': 'BEL', 'description': 'Beauly',
> 'gbttBookedArrival': '0715', 'gbttBookedArrivalNextDay': True,
> 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0715', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True,
> 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '1'}, {'tiploc': 'MUROORD', 'crs':
> 'MOO', 'description': 'Muir of Ord', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0720',
> 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0723', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True,
> 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '2'}, {'tiploc': 'CONONBR', 'crs':
> 'CBD', 'description': 'Conon Bridge', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0730',
> 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0731', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True,
> 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '1'}, {'tiploc': 'DINGWAL', 'crs':
> 'DIN', 'description': 'Dingwall', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0736',
> 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0739', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True,
> 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '1'}, {'tiploc': 'ALNESS', 'crs':
> 'ASS', 'description': 'Alness', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0751',
> 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0751', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True,
> 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '1'}, {'tiploc': 'IVRGRD', 'crs':
> 'IGD', 'description': 'Invergordon', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0756',
> 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0758', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True,
> 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '2'}, {'tiploc': 'FEARN', 'crs':
> 'FRN', 'description': 'Fearn', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0810',
> 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0811', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True,
> 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '1'}, {'tiploc': 'TAIN', 'crs':
> 'TAI', 'description': 'Tain', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0817',
> 'gbttBookedArrivalNextDay': True, 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0817',
> 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS', 'description': 'Inverness',
> 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime': '0700'}], 'destination':
> [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick', 'workingTime': '113100',
> 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True, 'isPublicCall': True,
> 'platform': '2'}, {'tiploc': 'ARDGAY', 'crs': 'ARD', 'description':
> 'Ardgay', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0833', 'gbttBookedArrivalNextDay':
> True, 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0833', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True,
> 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '2'}, {'tiploc': 'CULRAIN', 'crs':
> 'CUA', 'description': 'Culrain', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0837',
> 'gbttBookedArrivalNextDay': True, 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0837',
> 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS', 'description': 'Inverness',
> 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime': '0700'}], 'destination':
> [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick', 'workingTime': '113100',
> 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True, 'isPublicCall': True,
> 'platform': '1'}, {'tiploc': 'INVRSHN', 'crs': 'INH', 'description':
> 'Invershin', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0838', 'gbttBookedArrivalNextDay':
> True, 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0838', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True,
> 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '1'}, {'tiploc': 'LAIRG', 'crs':
> 'LRG', 'description': 'Lairg', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0849',
> 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0853', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True,
> 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '1'}, {'tiploc': 'ROGART', 'crs':
> 'ROG', 'description': 'Rogart', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0906',
> 'gbttBookedArrivalNextDay': True, 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0906',
> 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS', 'description': 'Inverness',
> 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime': '0700'}], 'destination':
> [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick', 'workingTime': '113100',
> 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True, 'isPublicCall': True,
> 'platform': '2'}, {'tiploc': 'GOLSPIE', 'crs': 'GOL', 'description':
> 'Golspie', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0917', 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0918',
> 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS', 'description': 'Inverness',
> 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime': '0700'}], 'destination':
> [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick', 'workingTime': '113100',
> 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True, 'isPublicCall': True,
> 'platform': '1'}, {'tiploc': 'BRORA', 'crs': 'BRA', 'description':
> 'Brora', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0928', 'gbttBookedDeparture': '0929',
> 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS', 'description': 'Inverness',
> 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime': '0700'}], 'destination':
> [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick', 'workingTime': '113100',
> 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True, 'isPublicCall': True,
> 'platform': '2'}, {'tiploc': 'HELMSDL', 'crs': 'HMS', 'description':
> 'Helmsdale', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0944', 'gbttBookedDeparture':
> '0947', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS', 'description': 'Inverness',
> 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime': '0700'}], 'destination':
> [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick', 'workingTime': '113100',
> 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True, 'isPublicCall': True,
> 'platform': '2'}, {'tiploc': 'KILDONN', 'crs': 'KIL', 'description':
> 'Kildonan', 'gbttBookedArrival': '0959', 'gbttBookedDeparture':
> '0959', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS', 'description': 'Inverness',
> 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime': '0700'}], 'destination':
> [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick', 'workingTime': '113100',
> 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True, 'isPublicCall': True,
> 'platform': '1'}, {'tiploc': 'KINBRAC', 'crs': 'KBC', 'description':
> 'Kinbrace', 'gbttBookedArrival': '1009', 'gbttBookedDeparture':
> '1009', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS', 'description': 'Inverness',
> 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime': '0700'}], 'destination':
> [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick', 'workingTime': '113100',
> 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True, 'isPublicCall': True,
> 'platform': '1'}, {'tiploc': 'FORSNRD', 'crs': 'FRS', 'description':
> 'Forsinard', 'gbttBookedArrival': '1021', 'gbttBookedArrivalNextDay':
> True, 'gbttBookedDeparture': '1021', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True,
> 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '2'}, {'tiploc': 'ALTNBRC', 'crs':
> 'ABC', 'description': 'Altnabreac', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True,
> 'isPublicCall': False, 'platform': '1'}, {'tiploc': 'SCSCLDR', 'crs':
> 'SCT', 'description': 'Scotscalder', 'gbttBookedArrival': '1038',
> 'gbttBookedDeparture': '1038', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True,
> 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '1'}, {'tiploc': 'GRGMASJ', 'crs':
> 'GGJ', 'description': 'Georgemas Junction', 'gbttBookedArrival':
> '1045', 'gbttBookedDeparture': '1049', 'origin': [{'tiploc':
> 'IVRNESS', 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000',
> 'publicTime': '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK',
> 'description': 'Wick', 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime':
> '1131'}], 'isCall': True, 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '1'},
> {'tiploc': 'THURSO', 'crs': 'THS', 'description': 'Thurso',
> 'gbttBookedArrival': '1059', 'gbttBookedDeparture': '1102', 'origin':
> [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS', 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime':
> '070000', 'publicTime': '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK',
> 'description': 'Wick', 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime':
> '1131'}], 'isCall': True, 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '1'},
> {'tiploc': 'GRGMASJ', 'crs': 'GGJ', 'description': 'Georgemas
> Junction', 'gbttBookedArrival': '1112', 'gbttBookedDeparture': '1114',
> 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS', 'description': 'Inverness',
> 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime': '0700'}], 'destination':
> [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick', 'workingTime': '113100',
> 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True, 'isPublicCall': True,
> 'platform': '1'}, {'tiploc': 'WICK', 'crs': 'WCK', 'description':
> 'Wick', 'gbttBookedArrival': '1131', 'origin': [{'tiploc': 'IVRNESS',
> 'description': 'Inverness', 'workingTime': '070000', 'publicTime':
> '0700'}], 'destination': [{'tiploc': 'WICK', 'description': 'Wick',
> 'workingTime': '113100', 'publicTime': '1131'}], 'isCall': True,
> 'isPublicCall': True, 'platform': '1'}]}

For the benefit of this example, I'd like to find thetime it departs from the CRS of 'INV' and arrives at 'DIN'

I haven't a clue how to do this

I've tried to filter the response, but didn't really get anywhere

Comment: Need more details. What is the schema? What programming language are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. I've updated the question to include some more detail. Using python

Comment: What is th schema? The response you posted isn't even valid JSON. Can you describe in words how the response is organized and how you expect to find the correct station? E.g. "In the 'locations' portion of the response, I want to find the entry whose `crs` is `stationA`, and return the `gbttBookedDeparture` from that entry."